# find the equation of an ellipse $x^2/8 +y^2/2= 1$ at point $ (2,1)$

Tags: geometry

pls help solve this question:
find the equation of an ellipse $x^2/8 +y^2/2= 1$ at point (2,1).
I already attempted it as follows:
taken x and y to be 2 and 1 respectively
hence, $(x-2)^2/8 +(y-1)^2/2= 1$
this gives: $x^2+4y^2-4x-8y=0$ as the equation of the ellipse. I don't know if I am on track.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! What do you mean by ‘ equation of a curve `at a point`’?

Comment: I guess you want to find the equation of the *tangent line* to the ellipse at the given point.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: By "at point (2,1)", do you mean centred on (2, 1), or tangent to (2,1), or something else?

Comment: well, I can't really tell. It's a question from my department.

Comment: @ThomasEmmanuel I'm pretty sure you have not quoted the question correctly. Find it printed somewhere and copy the words directly into your question (not in a comment).

Comment: Sir, I can now get your point. It should have been stated if the equation is a tangent or normal to the ellipse. I just consulted the source textbook and discovered it's an omission error of the questions on the department's bulletin board. Thanks.